# Is there any possible way to do UpperCase only "Vowel" form Column name = "last_name"?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle12c

I am working with HR.db with **Oracle 12c.**
I have one column with name "last_name" in employees database.

Now i want do is:-

last_name:- **"abel"**  to **"AbEl"**

and i want to apply on whole column data.

is there any possible way to query for this?

Comment: Do you want to replace only *English* vowels? Or do you need to support additional languages?

Answer (score 3):

You can use TRANSLATE function as per below:

> Ref Query([SQL-Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/4cf27/1)):

```
create table employees(id int, last_name varchar(100));

insert into employees values(1, 'able');

SELECT TRANSLATE(last_name, 'aeiou', 'AEIOU')  as last_name from employees;
```

> Syntax

The syntax for the TRANSLATE function in Oracle/PLSQL is:

```
TRANSLATE( string1, string_to_replace, replacement_string )
```

Parameters or Arguments

> string1

```
The string to replace a sequence of characters with another set of characters.
```

> string_to_replace

```
The string that will be searched for in string1.
```

> replacement_string

```
All characters in the string_to_replace will be replaced with the corresponding character in the replacement_string.
```

Comment: Thanx a lot jainvikram444... But there is an one problem with this solution... In the list i have name "Sewall"... Then result will be come with translate is "SEwAll"... First letter also will be small.

Comment: Does that apply to all uppercase letters in initial string just first one. What should be output from name "SeWall"?

Comment: i can get result with just small change in given query by @jainvikram444 "SELECT TRANSLATE(lower(last_name), 'aeiou', 'AEIOU')  as last_name from employees;"

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `translate` function of the oracle as following:

> ```
> SQL> SELECT TRANSLATE('abel', 'aeiou', 'AEIOU')
>   2  FROM DUAL;
>
> TRAN
> ----
> AbEl
>
> SQL>
> ```

Cheers!!

Comment: Thanx Tejash brother... But if first letter is not vowell then this function can not convert into small letter.